Hindu mantras and stotras to reduce sleep and get working energy
A person who is prone to fatigue and sleep, which mantra or stotra he/she can chant to reduce the fatigue and sleep hours yet they remain completely energised?
Also what are some mantras and stotras which can give a person immense energy to do any work.
For eg- I we chant the mantra we will be able to do two days work without any compulsion to sleep or fatigue but full of energy and joy .
